# Apache error 'operation failed' after trying to add a virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, zend-server

I'm trying to set up a zend project with the virtualhost but I can't get the example code from the quickstart to work.

I added this to the end of the existing lines in `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickstart.local
    DocumentRoot /path/to/quickstart/public

    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory /path/to/quickstart/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and this to my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 quickstart.local
```

The apache webserver works before I edited those file but after it I get an "The requested operation has failed" error.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the setting from

```
<Directory /path/to/quickstart/public>
```

to

```
<Directory "/path/to/quickstart/public">
```

or you can try to find out the problem by executing httpd.exe